# Alternative file writing and reading

Tags: matlab, opencv, file-io, yaml

For my project I have to save .yml file using OpenCV. Here is the structure of .yml file.

```
Block stride: [ 8, 8 ]
Cell size: [ 8, 8 ]
nbins: 9
blockhistsize: 36
Level1: 1
blocksperimg1: [ 152, 45 ]
Elements1: 246240
Scale1: 1.
Width1: 1224
Height1: 370
Features1:
   - 4.1452873498201370e-02
   - 3.7708058953285217e-02
   - 5.5512674152851105e-02
   ------------------------ 
   ------------------------
Features2:
   - 4.1452873498201370e-02
   - 3.7708058953285217e-02
   - 5.5512674152851105e-02
   ------------------------ 
   ------------------------
Features3:
   - 4.1452873498201370e-02
   - 3.7708058953285217e-02
   - 5.5512674152851105e-02
   ------------------------ 
   ------------------------
Features4:
   - 4.1452873498201370e-02
   - 3.7708058953285217e-02
   - 5.5512674152851105e-02
   ------------------------ 
   ------------------------
```

I have around 10,000 file and size of each file is around 60 MB. I have to read those yml files in MATLAB. I used [yamlmatlab](https://code.google.com/p/yamlmatlab/) to read those files. 
**Problem**
It takes five minutes to read **one** yml file. As I have around 10,000 files I will waste alot of time. I would appreciate if someone can propose an alternative route. You can find a simple yml file [here](http://www.filedropper.com/000000).

Comment: what information do you specifically need out of the file? If you can narrow this down, you can do some manual parsing that will likely be faster.

Comment: If you want a full data structure like what you're currently getting out of `yamlmatlab`, you're essentially asking for someone to write a parser for you (or rewrite the linked tool), which is not a trivial task and seems a bit beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: 10 000 files of 60 MB ... Well that's quite the data you have there. Your overall task seems quite heavy, maybe try to ask for a part ofthe code which you already tried.

Comment: I need to read the Features1, Features2, Features3, Features4 and so on, Level1,Level2, Level3, Level4 and so on, Scale1, Scale2, Scale3, Scale4 and so on, Elements1, Elements2, Elements3, Elements4 and so on, blocksperimg1, blocksperimg2, blocksperimg3, blocksperimg4 and so on and blockhistsize, @MZimmerman6

Comment: I have uploaded a sample yml file @Peut22

Comment: I am writing an example of something you could do, but I can not actually read your example file (dropbox is blocked) so I have to go solely off of your example. I only intend for you to use this as a base, to then do some more with it. Hopefully you understand regular expressions :)

Comment: Would I able to use it with matlab? As I need this data in matlab.

Comment: of course, all code is in the base install of matlab, no packages required.

Comment: I have updated the file link. Would you able to download the sample file @MZimmerman6

Comment: no file share websites are allowed, so no.

Comment: ------------------------ 
------------------------
These are not part of the file. I just put these to mention continuity of the values. @MZimmerman6

Comment: It works now but I have 13 levels like Features1, Features2... Features13. I am not sure how I can access those which are above Features9. Similarly I need to access Scale10,Scale11,Scale12 and Scale13 @MZimmerman6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I have written a basic text parser the works off of your example on this site. I am not able to get the file you posted (file sharing sites are blocked here). This does a bunch of text parsing using regular expressions. I will admit it is not the cleanest and can probably done easier, but it is a start.

```
function yaml = yamlparse(file)

    str = fileread(file);
    stride = regexpi(str,'Block stride: \[([ 0-9,]*)\]','tokens','once');
    cellSize = regexpi(str,'Cell size: \[([ 0-9,]*)\]','tokens','once');
    nbins = regexpi(str,'nbins: *([0-9]*)','tokens','once');
    blockhistsize = regexpi(str,'blockhistsize: *([0-9.]*)','tokens','once');
    level = regexpi(str,'Level[0-9]*: *([0-9]*)','tokens','once');
    blocksperimg = regexpi(str,'blocksperimg[0-9]: \[([ 0-    9.,]*)\]','tokens','once');
    elements = regexpi(str,'Elements[0-9]: *([0-9.]*)','tokens','once');
    scale = regexpi(str,'Scale[0-9]*: *([0-9.]*)','tokens','once');
    width = regexpi(str,'Width[0-9]*: *([0-9.]*)','tokens','once');
    height = regexpi(str,'Height[0-9]*: *([0-9.]*)','tokens','once');

    yaml.stride = eval(['[',stride{1},']']);
    yaml.cell_size = eval(['[',cellSize{1},']']);
    yaml.nbins = str2double(nbins);
    yaml.blockhistsize = str2double(blockhistsize);
    yaml.level = str2double(level);
    yaml.blocksperimg = eval(['[',blocksperimg{1},']']);
    yaml.elements = str2double(elements);
    yaml.scale = str2double(scale);
    yaml.width = str2double(width);
    yaml.height = str2double(height);

    features = regexpi(str,'Features[0-9]*:[\r\n \-0-9.e]*','match');
    featList = cell(1,1);
    for i = 1:numel(features)
        featNum = str2double(regexp(features{i},'Features([0-9]*)','tokens','once'));
        parts = regexpi(features{1},':','split');
        featVals = eval(['[',regexprep(strtrim(parts{2}),'\r\n',','),']']);
        featList{featNum} = featVals;
    end
    yaml.featList = featList;

end
```

It does not handle saving the multiple levels and scales you mentioned, but you can modify the code to do that yourself, it should not be too hard.

I can not vouch for the speed that this will run at with 60MB files, but I imagine it should be faster than 5 minutes.

**UPDATE**

Removed the unnecessary splitting on the "----------------" characters.

Comment: Let me try that. Can I get back to you if I have any problem with this approach. @Mzimmerman6

Comment: I will be in and out today, but sure

Comment: It works now but I have 13 levels like Features1, Features2... Features13. I am not sure how I can access those which are above Features9.

Comment: oh sorry, yeah i should have set up the regular expressions to accept that. Basically anywhere you see "[0-9]" make it "0-9]*" The asterisk means that you can have multiple digits. I have updated my code about to reflect this.

Comment: yeah I already made it work by studying more about regular expression. But it all because of your help. It solve my two problems. Like my question as well :)

Comment: @shah I am just curious, how long does the program take to run on a single file. You said yamlparser took 5 minutes, I am curious how much of an increase, if any at all, in speed this provided.

Comment: it takes around 25 seconds now. :). Can I share the version which I made it from your hep? may be you can help me to make more fast. @MZimmerman

Comment: you probably won't really get it much faster to be honest. Solely because you are parsing 60MB of text, which is very large and admittedly, regular expressions are not the fastest thing in the world. Also, you are using MATLAB, you cannot expect a whole lot of speed for text parsing like this. If you really want speed improvement, do your parsing and analysis in a compiled language. But even then, it is a still a big task